# how to find number of digits in a integer number if the number starting with zero?

Tags: java, count, digits

```
int a=000123,b=1
int len=(int)Math.log10(a)+1;
while((a=a/10)!=0)
{
  ++b;
}
System.out.println("Number of Digits:"+b);
```

output:
Number of Digits:3
it does not count the zero's if it takes place at left side. is there any way to count the digits with zero's also.

Comment: Use a `String` instead of `int`. Leading 0 has a different meaning than you think in Java.

Comment: You have to use strings to achieve this. Integers don't save leading zeros.

Comment: Be careful. `000123` (which java thinks is octal) is actually `83` (in decimal).

Answer (score 0):

If its an int (and not a String), it isn't stored how many zeros are in the front when you defined it -- `000123` is exactly the same as `0123`. However, starting a number with zero (one or several) means you are defining a number in octal representation. Thus `int a=000123; System.out.println(a);` will output `83`, probably not want you mean.

Comment: but it takes as the integer only

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the meaning of your comment.

Comment: a=000123 is treated as integer only

Comment: Yes, an int that is defined in octal representation (due to the leading zero). And as such, the value of the three variables `int a=000123, b=0123, c=83;` are absolutely indistinguishable within any following program code. It is all the same and there is no way to find out which variable was defined with how many leading zeros. Your question would only make sense if you would refer to strings instead of integers or if you forget about the leading zeros.

Comment: yes, your correct but when i trying with string method also it ignores the zeros 'a=000123 String sn=Integer.toString(a);    output: sn=123'

Comment: That's because you already lost the information about the leading zeros in `int a=000123;`. You have to start with a String in the very first place to keep any leading zeros: `String sn = "000123"`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I don't think you can do that 
best thing to do is get the number as a string and cast it to an int using nteger.parseInt when you want to calculate things

Comment: Be careful using the word "cast". `Integer.parseInt` is required instead.

Comment: may be your side wright, but I don't what's the logic?

Comment: yes shure you are right old habbitsn i will change the answer